# C# API HTTP Dynamic Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey I would like to achieve something that with dynamic parameters.

For example I have this Controller Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task TestParam(string firtname, string lastname, string persnr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Firstname: " + firtname);
    Console.WriteLine("Lastname: " + lastname);
    Console.WriteLine("Persnr: " + persnr);
}
```

Is it possible that my request can look like this:

| Url | Firstname | Lastname | Persnr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `URL/?firtname=Test&lastname=Test&persnr=123` | Test | Test | 123 |
| `URL/?firtname=Test&persnr=123` | Test |  | 123 |
| `URL/?lastname=Test&persnr=123` |  | Test | 123 |
| `URL/?persnr=123` |  |  | 123 |

So basically that I don't have to write all parameters?

Because if I make them optional with

```
TestParam(string firtname = "", string lastname = "", string persnr = "")
```

I have to write the url like that

```
URL/?firtname=&lastname=&persnr=123
```

to only see the `persnr.`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You a model and put all in there and check each one and use what you need.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: Hey that was actually my fault, because it is not my programm. I though it was asp.net but it isn't it is a standard c# programm. If it were on asp.net I came up with this solution [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-5.0). Isn't it much better then having a model class?

Comment: I can read the parameter like that `string firstname = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("firstname");`

Comment: With Asp.net having a model class is better because of automatic model binding and validation and it works with all HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a model class for your query parameters like this:

```
public class TestQuery
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Persnr { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can replace your `TestParam` signature like this:

```
public async Task TestParam([FromUri]TestQuery queryParams)
```

For more information please check [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Answer (score 1):

The Answer from Peter Csala worked but I'll have a second solution.

```
[HttpGet("{uri}")]
public async Task<string> TestParam(string uri)
{
    Uri myUri = new Uri("http://localhost:2000/?" + uri);

    string firstname = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("firstname");
    string lastname = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("lastname");
    string persnr = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("persnr");

    Console.WriteLine("Firstname: " + firtname);
    Console.WriteLine("Lastname: " + lastname);
    Console.WriteLine("Persnr: " + persnr);
}
```

This will read all parameters your write in the uri. For example lastname is not set in the uri it will be empty.

[HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-5.0)